# How do I debug an error on Heroku that won't show up in dev or production mode locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have an issue with an app that is doing one thing strangely (or not doing something I expect) only when pushed to Heroku and not in either development or production environments locally.

I tried putting binding.pry in my code, but it simply crashed Heroku.

How do I debug the instance on Heroku where the error is showing up?

**Edit 1**

I tried viewing my logs from Heroku, by doing `heroku logs --tail` but those are production environment logs. Not the detailed development logs that I would love to see. Is there anyway for me to retrieve development logs from Heroku to view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is using `heroku logs` from your app folder.

Comment: Yep...I have tried that, but the logs don't give me enough info. It is just the production environment logs, which are pretty sparse. Or are you suggesting something else? If so, how do I access those? i.e. I did `heroku logs --tail` and just looked at that output and it isn't as detailed as my development logs.

Comment: Set the `config.log_level` in your `production.rb` environment to `:debug` and you'll get more. You can also use `heroku logs -n 200` to get a longer tail.

Comment: Ahh....didn't know about the `config.log_level`. Will try that. Isn't `heroku logs --tail` better than just doing `heroku logs -n 200`?

Comment: Tail gives you a set number of tail lines in the log, while using `-n` you can set it yourself to see the whole output

Comment: Thanks much meng. Changing the `log_level :debug` helped me figure out the issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

heroku logs --app appname

and

heroku logs -t --app appname , This is also better option.